# Rails 3.1 & Sprockets & compiled JS files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

So just trying out Rails 3.1-rc1 with the Sprockets asset pipeline:

I run `rake assets:precompile`

and I get the /public/assets directory and the application.js file the MD5 hash:

```
application-266b6b0b4fbd28fc01145d90a4158b2f.js
```

But the problem is this:

When I update my JS and run `rake assets:precompile` I get more JS files and it doesnt delete the old ones.

I'm note sure how it works - the browser only picks up the first one and I have to manually delete the old ones. Which doesnt seem like how it should work.

Just a  side gripe: It seems I  have to run `rake assets:precompile` every time I change something. Which is painful.

(I guess there needs to be some docs on how this all works).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of js file is <file name>-<hash>.js.

That's made so that when you deploy new version of application to the production server your visitors would have to load new js file as well. The hash ensures that they will not have mixed up new application and old cached js that may break entire application taking into account dynamic nature of the web this days.

In most deployment scenarios you will have your app in new directory on the server and you will not have old compiled js files there.

Comment: OK - thats what I mean - the problem is that the old JS files are not getting removed. Are you saying that during development I have to precompile and then remove the old files everytime?

Comment: During development you don't need to precompile them. They get served right out of app/assets. They get compiled and served dynamically. You only precompile them in production to get the burden of compiling assets over and over off the application. Your compiled assets are supposed to be served by http server like Nginx or Apache.

Comment: Hmm... Ok - something weird was going on. I am using POW on my dev box, and that wasnt happening - it wasnt serving the files unless I did a pre-compile. Firebug was showing a 404 on application.css and application.js. But now it's all working. Maybe I just needed to reboot POW. (which I did when I rebooted my box). Thanks for the assistance. :-)